# Remove a node in XML using XmlSlurper in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I have a XML that contains a snippet like

```
<modules>
  <module>aaa</module>
  <module>bbb</module>
</modules>
```

Now I want to remove the node/tag  that contains the value "bbb" in the XML using XmlSlurper in groovy.

Any help?

Comment: hi, you might be able to do something like `def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(...); doc.children().findAll { item.text() == 'bbb' }.replaceNode {}` to removed the matched nodes.